# Generating XML files from SQL Server tables in C# using an XSD

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml, xsd

I'm trying to generate an XML file for a dataset across several SQL Server tables. I have an XSD definition for the desired dataset and was wondering if it's possible to use C#'s data objects to point to the tables, note their relationships, extract the data and populate an XML file going via the XSD validate. I'm fine with setting up the tables to EXACTLY represent the hierarchies in the final XML file if this helps.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following:

1) Create C# class files from the XSD using the xsd.exe tool.

2) Use an ORM to map the database objects to your C# classes.

3) Use the XmlSerializer class to convert C# objects to an XML document which will match your XSD.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/943242d1(v=vs.110).aspx